# mostrar footer y header con contenido scrollable

Tags: html, css

**Nota:** Estoy Usando el framework Boostrap 3

En pantalla de escritorio esta bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en dispositivo móviles no aparece al final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código html que tengo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Productos</title>

<?php include 'includes/head_comun.php'; ?>

</head>

<?php include 'includes/encabezado.php'; ?>

<div class="container" >
<br><br>


<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading" align="center"><h3>PRODUCTOS</h3>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="panel-body">

   <div class="row" align="center">
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
      Nuevo Producto
    </button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="table-responsive">

    <table id="grid" class="table table-hover table-condensed nowrap dt-responsive table-bordered" cellpadding="0">

      <thead>
        <tr class="active">
          <th>Codigo</th>
          <th >Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
          <th>Valor Unitario</th>
          <th>Valor</th>
          <th>Kardex</th>
          <th>Opciones</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <?php

      foreach($matrizProductos as $producto):  ?>

      <tr>

       <td><?php echo $producto["cod_producto"]?></td>
       <td><?php echo $producto["nombre"]?></td>
       <td><?php echo $producto["cantidad"]?></td>
       <td><?php echo $producto["valor_unitario"]?></td>
       <td><?php echo $producto["valor"]?></td>


       <td><a href="vista/ver_movimientos.php?id_producto=<?php echo $producto["id_producto"]?>">Ver Movimientos</a>

        <a href="vista/frm_movimiento.php?id_producto=<?php echo $producto["id_producto"] ?>"><input type="button" value="Acción" class="btn btn-warning"></a>

       </td>

       <td>

         <a href="vista/frm_editar.php?id_producto=<?php echo $producto["id_producto"]?>"><input type='button' name='edi' value='Editar' class="btn btn-info"></a>

         <a href="modelo/borrar.php?id_producto=<?php echo $producto["id_producto"]?>"><input type='button' name='del' value='Eliminar' class="btn btn-danger"></a>

       </td>
     </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
 </div>

 <!-- Modal new -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="nuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo Producto</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

      <form  role="form" style="margin:0 auto" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="modelo/insertar.php">

        <div class="form-group" >
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Codigo</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cod" placeholder="Ingrese Codigo" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomb" placeholder="Ingrese nombre"  required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" name="agregar" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
          <button type="reset" name="limpiar" class="btn btn-primary">Limpiar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>

        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end modal new-->   </div>
```

Este es el codigo de piePagina.php:

```
<footer >
<h4 class="muted credit" id="pie">&copy <?php echo date('Y');?> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/juanzu10/" style="text-decoration: none;" id="sincolor" target="_blank"> - Juanzu. </a></h4>
</footer>
```

Codigo CSS:

```
html, body{
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',
'Helvetica Neue',
Helvetica, Arial, sans-serief;
}

.navbar{
margin-bottom: 0;
}
th{
text-align: center;
}
td{
text-align: center;
}


footer {
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
background:black;
color:white;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;}

#sincolor{
color: #086108;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.post .thumb {
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-right: 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html
{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    padding: 60px 0px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header, footer
{
    background: #72CEF2;
    padding: 9px 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

header{top:0;}
footer{bottom:0;}

div[role="main"]
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}

section
{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>Title</header>
    <div role="main">
        <section>
Hello<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />World!
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>copyright</footer>
</body>
```

merito a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741871/how-to-get-a-scrollbar-in-a-div-with-fixed-header-and-footer?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

En vez de utilizar una `position: absolute;` para posesionar tu elemento siempre abajo utiliza `position: fixed;`, ya que este último se posiciona de forma relativa a la ventana del navegador.

```css
    html, body{
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',
    'Helvetica Neue',
 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serief;
    }

    .navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    th{
    text-align: center;
    }
    td{
    text-align: center;
    }


    footer {
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    position: fixed
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;}

    #sincolor{
    color: #086108;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .post .thumb {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 0;
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Productos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   

    </head>
 <body>


    <div class="container" >
    <br><br>


    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading" align="center"><h3>PRODUCTOS</h3>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="panel-body">

       <div class="row" align="center">
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
          Nuevo Producto
        </button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="table-responsive">

        <table id="grid" class="table table-hover table-condensed nowrap dt-responsive table-bordered" cellpadding="0">

          <thead>
            <tr class="active">
              <th>Codigo</th>
              <th >Nombre</th>
              <th>Cantidad</th>
              <th>Valor Unitario</th>
              <th>Valor</th>
              <th>Kardex</th>
              <th>Opciones</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <?php

          foreach($matrizProductos as $producto):  ?>

          <tr>

           <td><?php echo $producto["cod_producto"]?></td>
           <td><?php echo $producto["nombre"]?></td>
           <td><?php echo $producto["cantidad"]?></td>
           <td><?php echo $producto["valor_unitario"]?></td>
           <td><?php echo $producto["valor"]?></td>


           <td><a href="vista/ver_movimientos.php?id_producto=<?php echo $producto["id_producto"]?>">Ver Movimientos</a>

            <a href="vista/frm_movimiento.php?id_producto=<?php echo $producto["id_producto"] ?>"><input type="button" value="Acción" class="btn btn-warning"></a>

           </td>

           <td>

             <a href="vista/frm_editar.php?id_producto=<?php echo $producto["id_producto"]?>"><input type='button' name='edi' value='Editar' class="btn btn-info"></a>

             <a href="modelo/borrar.php?id_producto=<?php echo $producto["id_producto"]?>"><input type='button' name='del' value='Eliminar' class="btn btn-danger"></a>

           </td>
         </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
     </table>
     </div>

     <!-- Modal new -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="nuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo Producto</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          <form  role="form" style="margin:0 auto" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="modelo/insertar.php">

            <div class="form-group" >
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Codigo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cod" placeholder="Ingrese Codigo" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomb" placeholder="Ingrese nombre"  required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" name="agregar" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
              <button type="reset" name="limpiar" class="btn btn-primary">Limpiar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>

            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end modal new-->   </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php include 'includes/piePagina.php'; ?>
<footer >
 <h4 class="muted credit" id="pie">&copy <?php echo date('Y');?> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/juanzu10/" style="text-decoration: none;" id="sincolor" target="_blank"> - Juanzu. </a></h4>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

> Te dejo un [link](http://es.learnlayout.com/position.html) donde
>   hablan sobre las posiciones css.

Comment: Si es una de las soluciones, pero será que habrá una donde siempre me muestre abajo sin necesidad de estar bajando con el scrool. Espero que me haga entender.

Comment: quieres una area scrollable que se mantenga tu footer y tu header @Juanzu

Comment: @JackNavaRow Exacto!